# Quizmaker: two times draggable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a quiz website. Now I have a question regarding how to make the sentence multiple times draggable.

You can see the quiz [here](https://costacct.github.io/)

**My question is**: I can drag the sentence from right container to the left container, and then it will tell me whether i'm wrong. I want to drag the wrong placed sentence again, however i cannot drag it anymore. I attach below a screenshot of the html and js file.

[image]
[image]

Can you give me a hint why i cannot drag it from left container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you drop item in the wrapper you create a new `<li>` element that will contain the value of the dragged element, but that `<li>` element is not draggable